# Explanation of the following nested for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I need an explanation for the following nested for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 30;

    for (int outer = 0; outer < 3; outer++) {
        for (int inner = 4; inner > 1; inner--) {
            x = x + 3; // 3
            y = y - 2; // 28
            if (x == 6) {
                break;
            }
            x = x + 3; // 6
        }
        y = y - 2; // 26
    }

    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

The output is 54 6, but I am confused how this is the answer. I've tried going through this myself, and I've found that the for loop for 'inner' results in `4 3 2 4 3 2 4 3 2`. The 'outer' for loop results in `0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2`.
How do x and y play into this and get these values? Thank you so much!

Comment: `x` and `y` are defined outside / before the loops, that means they are getting changed depending on the iterations of the loops...

Comment: I figured that out already. But how exactly are they changing based on the loops?

Comment: Your statements `x = x + 3;` and `y = y - 2;` are changing them, by calculating the result on the right side and assigning it to the variable on the left side of the `=`.

Comment: Your outer loop is being run `3` times (for values `0, 1, 2`). For each iteration of your outer loop, the inner loop is also being run `3` times (for values `4, 3, 2` each). Can you pinpoint to what exactly is unclear?

Comment: I understand that part, but I am confused as to what I am supposed to substitute for x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably confuse the loop indices, outer and inner, with x and y, but they are different variables.

The outer loop is executed 3 times, the inner loop 9 times ((3 times for each iteration of the outer loop).
So both are executed completely, because the if which could break the loop is never entered.

x, which is increased of 3 twice in the inner loop only, will reach the value of (3+3)*9 = 54

y will be decreased of 2 9 times in the inner loop and 3 times in the outer loop. So it will be 30 - (2 * 9) - (2*3) = 6

Loop samples

```
outer=0
 inner=4
   x=3
   Y=28
   x=6
 inner=3
   x=9
   y=26
   x=12
 inner=2
   x=15
   y=24
   x=18
 end of inner loop
 y=22
 outer=1
  inner=4
 ....
 and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was mixing the loop indices with the variables. Instead, I used the for loops to determine how many times I would run each operation. Thank you so much.